# C++ BigIntegers and the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern Issue

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, biginteger, crtp

I'm implementing a Big Integer library where the user can choose between fixed precision or arbitrary precision integers. Since great part of the code is shared between the two entities I've decided to use the CRTP to implement the Integer operations just once.

In short there is a base class named UInteger and two derived classes named UIntegerFP (fixed precision) and UIntegerAP (arbitrary precision).

Follows a skeleton of the implementation:

```
template <typename Derived>
class UInteger
{
public:
    UInteger<Derived> &operator +=(const UInteger<Derived> &rhs);
    ...
};

template <int blocks>
class UIntegerFP : public UInteger<UIntegerFP>
{
public:
    int get_size() { return m_len; }
    void set_size(int size) { m_len = len; }
private:
    std::array<uint32_t, blocks>    m_data;
    int                             m_len;  
};

class UIntegerAP : public UInteger<UIntegerAP>
{
public:
    int get_size() { return m_data.size(); }
    void set_size(int size) { m_data.resize(len); } 
private:
    std::vector<uint32_t>           m_data;
};
```

The base class uses a couple of methods exposed by the derived classes to interact with implementation dependent aspects (ie like get_size/set_size).

My problem:

I want to implement a global binary operator+() that returns the result of the operation by value in the UInteger "generic" header file in this way:

```
template <typename Derived>
UInteger<Derived> operator+(const UInteger<Derived> &x0, 
                            const UInteger<Derived> &x1)
{
    Derived res = static_cast<Derived>(x0);
    x0 += x1;
    return x0;
}
```

The problem is that, since the result is returned by value, it is casted to the base class type loosing the implementation details (e.g. the m_data vector destructor is called).
Obviously I do not get this problem if I define the function to return a Derived type  by value:

```
template <typename Derived>
Derived operator+(const UInteger<Derived> &x0, 
                  const UInteger<Derived> &x1)
{
    Derived res = static_cast<Derived>(x0);
    x0 += x1;
    return x0;
}
```

But I don't like too much this approach, epecially from a design point of view.

Is there a better solution to such problem? Maybe I should define such operators directly just for the derived classes?
Is there someone thinking that the CRTP is not very appropriate here and maybe is better to directly implement just one UInteger class in this way:

```
template <bool dynamic = true> 
class UInteger
{
...
private:
    std::array<uint32_t> m_data;
    int m_len; <- how much of m_data array is actually in use
}
```

and if the bool "dynamic" value is false I never reallocate the vector obtaining something similar to the UIntegerFP template class. Maybe (if the compiler is smart enough) , since the boolean is a const template parameter, I also abtain something like conditional code compilation?!

Suggestions of any type are very welcome,

Thanks,
Davide

Comment: "But I don't like too much this approach, especially from a design point of view."  What?  This is the only sane option.  What's the design problem?

Comment: Unrelated, when I did this, I made two "storage" classes, one dynamically resizable, and one static, and a `template<class storage_class> class UIInteger` that had a `storage_class` member that it operated on.  Bypasses all the weird template logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you want to use CRTP here in this way.

CRTP is the natural way to implement the actual details of the `=` and `+=` operations, when only the memory management is done via the derived methods. Such design clearly separates the two task of arithmetic and memory management to different classes. The `+` (binary) operator is then best implemented as stand-alone function template.

Something like this:

```
namespace biginteger_details {
  template<typename UInteger>
  class UIntegerBase      // CRTP base, implementing the arithmetics
  {
    using uint32_t = std::uint32_t;
    using size_t = std::size_t;
    // access to data: all functionality is implemented through these methods
    uint32_t&block(size_t i)       { return static_cast<      UInteger*>(this)->m_data[i]; }
    uint32_t block(size_t i) const { return static_cast<const UInteger*>(this)->m_data[i]; }
    size_t size() const    { return static_cast<const UInteger*>(this)->size(); }
    void resize(size_t n)  { static_cast<UInteger*>(this)->resize(n); }
  public:
    // assignment operator: allow assignment from any UInteger type
    template<typename UI>
    UInteger&operator=(UIntegerBase<UI> const&other)
    {
      resize(other.size());
      for(size_t i=0; i!=size(); ++i)
        block(i) = other.block(i);
      return static_cast<UInteger&>(*this);
    }
    // add and assign: allow adding any UInteger type
    template<typename UI>
    UInteger&operator+=(UIntegerBase<UI> const&other)
    {
      // your code here using block(), size(), and resize()
      return static_cast<UInteger&>(*this);
    }
  };

  template<std::size_t nblock=8>
  struct UIntegerFP
  : UIntegerBase<UIntegerFP<nblock>>
  {
    static constexpr std::size_t max_blocks=nblock;
    // 1 data
    std::array<std::uint32_t,nblock> m_data;
    std::size_t m_size=0;
    // 2 interface to base
    std::size_t size() const { return m_size; }
    void resize(std::size_t n)
    {
      if(n>nblock) throw std::out_of_range("exceeding capacity");
      m_size = n;
    }
    // 3 constructors
    //   copy constructor from any UInteger type
    template<typename UI>
    UIntegerFP(UIntegerBase<UI> const&other)
    { this->operator=(other); }
  };

  struct UIntegerAP
  : UIntegerBase<UIntegerAP>
  {
    static constexpr std::size_t max_blocks=~(std::size_t(0));
    // 1 data,
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> m_data;
    // 2 interface to base
    std::size_t size() const { return m_data.size(); }
    void resize(std::size_t n)
    { m_data.resize(n); }
    // 3 constructors
    //   copy constructor from any UInteger type
    template<typename UI>
    UIntegerAP(UIntegerBase<UI> const&other)
    { this->operator=(other); }
  };

  // functions best take UIntegerBase<UI> arguments, for example:

  // operator + as stand alone function template
  template<typename Ulhs, typename Urhs>
  inline std::conditional_t<(Ulhs::max_blocks > Urhs::max_blocks), Ulhs, Urhs>
  operator+(UIntegerBase<Ulhs> const&lhs, UIntegerBase<Urhs> const&rhs)
  {
    std::conditional_t<(Ulhs::max_blocks > Urhs::max_blocks), Ulhs, Urhs>
    result=lhs;
    return result+=rhs;
  }
} // namespace biginteger_details;
using biginteger_details::UIntegerFP; 
using biginteger_details::UIntegerAP;
// note: biginteger_details::operator+ will be found by ADL (argument dependent look-up)
```

Comment: HI Walter, I don't understand your operator+ implementation.
In practice, you are setting the function return type as 
* UIntegerAP if one of the template types is an UIntegerAP
* Ulhs, otherwise (here I suppose you intend UIntegerFP)
Is that right?

Comment: @Davide Yes, that's what I did. I've changed that now to return the higher precision of the two input types, similar to what the language does for built-in types. But you can design that aspect as you like.

Comment: thanks for your kind explaination. That is pretty clear. What you think about creating a unique UInteger class that takes as template parameter the container type?

    `template <typename container_type>
    struct UInteger  
    {  
          container_type m_data;
         ....    
    }`  

And have two containers like
    
   `template <typename size>
    struct StaticArray {
        std::array 
    };`

    `struct DynamicArray {
         std::vector<uint32_t> m_impl;
    };`
defining the data ops like resize. Maybe at the end the result is equal. What you think is the best approach

Comment: @Davide Yes, you could also have that design. In the end both will be pretty similar, as long as you always restrict the interface between the arithmetic class and the memory class to a bar minimum and use fully templated functionality (so that the memory is a mere implementation detail).

Answer (score 0):

In your `operator+` implementation, in practice, you are setting the function return type as:

- `UIntegerAP` if one of the template types is an `UIntegerAP`.
- `Ulhs`, otherwise (here I suppose you intend `UIntegerFP`).

Is that right?

Now... what if the `UIntegerAP` is a template as well? For example defined like this:

```
template <typename block_type>
class UIntegerAP
{
   ....
private:    
    std::vector<block_type> m_data;
}
```

I cannot use `UIntegerAP` type in the `operator+` declaration anymore.